# If the given array contains one or more negative int return False. Else return True

Tags: javascript

```
function zero_negativity(arr){

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

    if (arr[i] < 0){
        console.log("False");
        break
    }
    else {
        console.log("True");
    }
}
```

};

zero_negativity([1,2,3,4,5]);

I would like for it to return true if there is not a single negative number.

Comment: You're not passing anythimg tp the function

Comment: Why are you changing the question now that you've got answers? What is it that you *actually* want to do? See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call function **zero_negativity** with argument **arr**. Your code could be simplified:

```js
arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

function zero_negativity(arr){
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      return arr[i] >= 0;
}

var result = zero_negativity(arr);
console.log(result);
```

However, I think, your function should look like this one:

```js
function zero_negativity(arr){
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    if (arr[i] < 0)
      return false;

  return true;
}

console.log(zero_negativity([1,2,3,4,5])); // true
console.log(zero_negativity([1,2,0,8,0])); // true
console.log(zero_negativity([1,2,3,-4,5])); // false
console.log(zero_negativity([-4,-6,-2])); // false
```

Comment: It worked thank you!!

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the array as a parameter.

```
zero_negativity(arr);
```

Comment: I have that fixed:  
function zero_negativity(arr){
 
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  
  if (arr[i] < 0){
   console.log("False");
   break
  }
  else {
   console.log("True");
  }
 }
};


zero_negativity([1,2,3,4,5]);
I would like for it to console.log either FALSE if the array has one or more negative int in it

Comment: @DanielYanez
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min you can use this as a reference to check if there are any negative numbers and modify your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the array into the function - you need to change it to zero_negativity(arr) - that said, I have provided another solution to the outcome. Simply getting the min number of the array and checking that to see if its less than 0. Of course this assumes that the passed array contains numbers- if not you will need to parse the array items into numbers.

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
let arr1 = [1,2,3,-4,5];

function zero_negativity(array){
  let minNum = Math.min(...array);
  return minNum < 0 
}

console.log(zero_negativity(arr)); // console logs false
console.log(zero_negativity(arr1)); // console logs true
```

Comment: Thank you, I realized it and fixed my question. I am new to Stackoverflow.

Comment: @DanielYanez - welcome to SO - when you ask a question - and get answers - don't change the question  based on the outcome of the answer. If an answer solves your problem, you can sleect it as the desired solution (for example if you liked my solution - then you select it as the one you want to use. But then your question and the resultant answers act as a source of information for other dev's in the future. So changing the quesiton negates the info respository. You don't have to accept any answers and its great if you learn what you could improve, but you need to leave the question as stated.